# apache failed to start with no error logs

Tags: python, django, apache, wsgi, error-log

this day i got an issue

my apache has failed to restart my django app, i dont know why.
and the worst is , it doesnt out with any error log , just blank!

this problem make me confuse ,need help.

> alif@alif-VirtualBox:/var/www/mywebsite/website$ service apache2 restart
>    * Restarting web server apache2     [fail]

/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin admin@musicplayer.vhost
    ServerName www.musicplayer.vhost
    ServerAlias musicplayer.vhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mywebsite


    Alias /static /var/www/mywebsite/website/static
    <Directory /var/www/mywebsite/website/static>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/mywebsite/website/website>

            <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
            </Files>

    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess mywebsite python-path=/var/www/mywebsite:/var/www/mywebsite/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup mywebsite
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mywebsite/website/website/wsgi.py

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info,notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
```

wsgi.py on mywebsite

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
path = '/var/www/mywebsite/website'
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "website.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to make sure nothing is listening on port 80. I'm not sure what the `website.settings` contains but it is possible that either this apache instance is trying to use the same port as another, or something else is running on port 80. (this is the default port). You can check if something might be using the port with `netstat -tulpn | grep :80`

You can alter the port of this server to avoid the collision or, stop the other process.

Comment: sure bro, your answer help me , a lot